# Make font-awesome icon size increase on mouseover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome with bootstrap 4 cards, is there anyway to increase the size of the font-awesome icon (bottom right) when I mouse over the button?

in this case `<i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-5x"></i>`

**Here is the HTML**

```
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card card-inverse card-success">
                        <div class="card-block bg-success">
                            <div class="rotate">
                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <center><a class="btn btn-success show" target="1" role="button"><h5 class="text-uppercase">open cases &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-1x"></i></h5></a></center>
                            <h1 class="display-1"><center>7</center></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Here is what it presently looks like**

[image]

Comment: `.card:hover .fa { font-size: 6em; }` ?

Comment: or use the `transform: scale()` css. Both look better adding a `transition` for the `.fa` so it will animate.

Comment: not without `javascript`, there is no parent selector, to target icon when you `hover` over the button

Comment: There's no need for JavaScript. CSS `:hover` should work.

Comment: @Philip, is there a way to target a specific fa ? you see if i use your solution it is expanding the arrow on the button which i dont want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.card:hover > .card-block > .rotate > .fa {  }` to target the icon.

Then you can use `font-size: 6em;` to enlarge the font or use the `transform: scale()` css.

Both look better adding a `transition` for the `.fa` so it will animate on hover.

EDIT: The `transition` should be set on `.card > .card-block > .rotate > .fa {  }` (so without the `:hover`).

Example:
    `.card > .card-block > .rotate > .fa {  transition: font-size 0.35s ease;   }`
    `.card:hover > .card-block > .rotate > .fa {  font-size: 5em;   }`

(Don't forget to add extra rules with prefixes for cross-browser compatibility, see caniuse.com or W3schools for reference.)

Comment: this looks nice and works.. testing it now with a transition effect

Comment: i did this and it worked: .card:hover > .card-block > .rotate > .fa { font-size: 6em; transition: 1s ease-out;}

Comment: But on mouse-out it might not animate I think.. ( because the CSS rule with `transition` doesn't apply anymore)

Comment: See the edit-part; just create 2 rules:  `:hover` -> what to change  2) other -> the `transition`

Comment: i tried this but not animating.. .card { transition: all .1s ease-in-out; }

Comment: Not on the card, on the `.fa`, but with a non-hovered parent (see example)

Answer (score 6):

look maybe this help you

```
.rotate .fa.fa-folder-open:hover{
  font-size:6em;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVNbJY)

Comment: need .fa.fa-folder-open to expand when i mouseover the button not the icon

Comment: @user3436467 you can accomplish this by using some jquery tricks , try something like `$('.fa.fa-folder-open').hide();`  and then for the other action `$('fa.fa-folder-close').show();`    you can also use add class option in jquery , this stuff you can make in various ways. and sorry for the missy here comments is not a good place to write codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what I used to create the hover effect that scales the icon's size.

```
<i class="fas fa-file-pdf" style="cursor: pointer"
   onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFA500'; 
   this.style.transform='scale(1.2)'"

   onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'; 
   this.style.transform='scale(1.0)'"

   @click="iconClicked(data, 'pdf')"></i>
```